# Convert Time stamp to readable format

Tags: php, timestamp

I need to conver timestamp to `2016-07-12 format`. This is what I tried.

```
$selectedDate=date('m/d/Y H:i:s', '1465430400000');
```

I got `08/23/48407 00:00:00` I need to conver it to `2016-07-12 format`.
Please Note: Here the format m/d/Y H:i:s isn't the matter. I'm getting wrong date is the problem

Any suggetion would be appricieated.

Comment: you already have `m/d/Y H:i:s` and you're asking for the `Y-m-d` format? do you really need to post this?

Comment: @ChetanAmeta I treid already. I'm getting 48495-04-03 as the date.

Comment: You should trye to divide the timestamp by 1000 because it's in millisecond I think

Comment: try @smarx ans devide by 1000

Comment: @Mika A Correct!. I'm getting this value from another source which I dont have any idea. You are correct. Thanks :)

Comment: @smarx added the answer, you should accept it as the correct one

Comment: Yes I will do that. Need to stay for another 7m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your timestamp is 1000x what `date()` expects, so try first dividing it by 1000 (and then, of course, use the right date format):

```
$selectedDate = date('Y-m-d', 1465430400000/1000);
```

Comment: I'm getting this value from another source which I dont have any idea. You are correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Date in Any format:

```
<?php  $date1 = strtotime($old_date);
   echo  $date = date("y-M-d", $date1); ?>
```

[Complete list of format options](http://php.net/date)